# Rails 5. How to use an uploads controller to handle bulk uploads by dispatching each record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, ruby-on-rails-5

This is Rails 5 with Mongoid.

I have a MVC structure for load balancers.  The model and the controller do all the validation and sanitising I want and need.  However, I want to be able to send an array of balancer data structures to an `upload` controller, which will verify the upload is in a sane format, and then iterate over the array dispatching to the `balancers` controller to validate, insert, or upsert each entry as needed -- and accumulate statistics so that at the end of the iteration I can produce an HTML or JSON rendering of success count and detailed errors.

I'm pretty sure I need to frob the `params` structure as part of each iteration/dispatch, but it's unclear how, or whether I want to use the `BalancersController`'s `#new`, `#create`, `#update`, `#save`, or what method in order to get the validation to work and the insert/upsert to be done properly.

I haven't yet been able to find anything that seems to describe this exact sort of bulk-upload scenario, so any/all help & guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks!
(There are serveral other models/controllers I want to push through here; the balancer case is just an example.)

I've *sort* of got the collecting of the statistics summary down, but I' having trouble dispatching to the `balancers` controller to actually update the database with anything other than `nil`.

[edited]

Here's an simple example model:

```
class Puppet::Dbhost

  include ::PerceptSys
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  validates(:pdbfqdn,
            :presence   => true)

  field(:pdbfqdn,
        :type       => String)
  field(:active,
        :type       => Mongoid::Boolean)
  field(:phases,
        :type       => Array)

  index(
    {
      :pdbfqdn      => 1,
    },
    {
      :unique       => true,
      :name         => 'dbhosts_pdbfqdn',
    }
  )

end                             # class Puppet::Dbhost
```

The `uploads` controller has a route `post('/uploads/puppet/dbhosts(.:format)', :id => 'puppet_dbhosts', :to => 'uploads#upload')`.

The document containing upload information looks like this:

```
{
  "puppet_dbhosts" : [
    {
      "pdbfqdn" : "some-fqdn",
      "active" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

The `uploads#upload` method vets the basic syntax of the document, and then is where I get stuck.  I've tried

```
before_action(:upload, :set_upload_list)
def set_upload_list
  params.require(:puppet_dbhosts)
end

def upload
  reclist = params.delete(:puppet_dbhosts)
  reclist.each do |dbhrec|
    params[:puppet_dbhost] = dbhrec
    dbhost = Puppet::Dbhost.new
    dbhost.update
  end
end
```

In very broad strokes.  The logic for validating a `puppet_dbhost` entry is embedded in the model and the controller; the `uploads` controller is meant to simply dispatch and delegate, and tabulate the results.  There a several models accepting uploads in this manner, hence the separate controller.

Comment: you should show your attempt, it will probably be easier to fix that way. Also, calling one controller's methods from another is kind of a noob trap. Not saying it's something you should never do, but it's better to keep controllers as just the means of fielding requests/responses from the client, and if you need to share some code between them, extract it to a shared class or module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel sheeeepish.  Obviously the correct path is to abstract the generic upload methods and logic into a separate module and mix it in.  Routes can be adjusted.  So no need for controllers to know about the internals of others for this scenario.  Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Can you explain more what this means? I have the same question but I don't understand the obviousness of the answer.